# Bokeh - clear previous entries of 'figure' (plot)

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to update my plot based on the user selection (i want the entire figure/plot to be refreshed each time the selection changes), but i am seeing that the plot gets added to the previously created plots on the same plot area. I search for similar posts here but couldn't get an answer i am looking for. I came across [this](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/crossfilter/main.py#L72-L73) but i couldn't get it to work.

If the user selects 3 times, the plot shows data from all those 3 selections, instead of overriding with fresh data each time. I find it very strange that the default behavior is not to refresh. Any help on this issue is greatly appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
button = Button(label='Plot')
output = Paragraph()
cluster_slider = Slider(start=2,end=10,step=1,title='Clusters',value=3)    
select1 = Select(title='Parameter1',value='Value', options=['Age','Value','Industry'])
select2 = Select(title='Parameter1',value='Age', options=['Age','Value','Industry'])
```

```
p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)

def plot_clusters():
    <processing logic>
    p.circle(dfinput[sel1], dfinput[sel2], size=2, color=colors, alpha=0.5)

button.on_click(plot_clusters)

lay_out = layout([[cluster_slider,[select1,select2],button],[output]])
curdoc().add_root(lay_out)
curdoc().add_root(p)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually solved it. Posting it here for others' benefit:
Trick is to define a layout with a row of 2 items and update the second item upon click/change.

```
from bokeh.layouts import layout,row
p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)

def plot_clusters():
    <processing logic>
    p=figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
    p.circle(x,y, size=2, color=colors, alpha=0.5)
    lay_out.children[1]=p # set the second element of layout to the new figure

button.on_click(plot_clusters)

lay_out = row(controls,p) #controls can be select, slider etc.
curdoc().add_root(lay_out)
```